# App was deactivated because of violating the Facebook Platform Policy 6.1 (Why it showing the response code as 0)

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have received a mail from the Facebook developer regarding the deactivation of my app because of violating policy 6.1.

Here I have checked using the tester account. It shows the error as "Something went wrong" with the below code.

```
requestCode = 64206
resultCode = 0
```

Note: I also got the SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing query. [extra]:  once.

I have checked with other appId with the same implementation code, it works fine and returns the **resultCode as -1**. It makes the login successful.

Used the customTabs for the login.
Using Facebook SDK version 8.2.

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile");
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity) context, permissions);
```

[image]

Message from the Facebook Policy:

```
During Login, your app is crashing or hanging excessively, creating a broken experience for people trying to use your app.

To make sure this flow runs smoothly, check that you've integrated Facebook Login correctly. We recommend that you test Login on all integrations. If you have not already done so, please:
    
    • Here's our quickstart guide for implementing Facebook Login for Android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android
    • We encourage you to test your Login integration following these steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow/
    • Best Practices for Login can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices
    
    For more information, visit:
      - Developer Policies: https://developers.facebook.com/devpolicy
      - Platform Terms: https://developers.facebook.com/terms
    
    Once you’ve updated your app, please go to https://developers.facebook.com/appeal to appeal. A member of our team will get back to you within 48 hours.
```

Comment: was it fixed or are you still working on it. if it's fixed would you like to share its solution?

Comment: Checking this...

Comment: Did you have any solutions?